# Combine two arrays in order to generate an key with 2 values

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
array (size=7)
  'form' => string 'form-elements'
  'device' => string 'computer'
  'company' => string 'sdfsdf'
  'Naam' => string 'sdfsdfs'
  'phone' => string 'dfsdfsd'
  'email' => string 'andrey6ssss13@gmail.comrty'
  'mesaj' => string 'dasdasd'
```

And I store in `$_SESSION` for every key one more value (`$_SESSION['key from $_POST'.'_type']`), the "type", for example I need to serialize `["company","sdfsdf","1"]` is there a way to generate the array like this :

```
array (size=7)
  'form' => string 'form-elements'
  'device' => string 'computer'
  'company' => array (
       'sdfsdf'
       '1' 
       )
  'Naam' => array(
     'sdfsdfs'
     '0'
     )
  'phone' => array (
     'dfsdfsd'
      '3'
      )
```

etc.

So I have this function that does what I need but I have to do a different approach approach, I need to combine `$_POST`  array with `$_SESSION['$_POST key'.'_type']` in order to have 2 values for `$_POST` key

```
function arrayDisplay($input){
    $goodKeys = array_diff(array_keys($input), array('form', 'captcha'));
    $data = array();
    foreach ($goodKeys as $goodKey) {
       $data[$goodKey] = $input[$goodKey];
    }
    return '[' . implode(
        ', ',
        array_map(
            function ($v, $k) {
                $s = 0;
                if(isset($_SESSION[$k.'_type']))
                {
                 $s = $_SESSION[$k.'_type'];    
                }
                    if(is_array($v))
                        {
                        $v = implode(",",$v);
                        }
                return sprintf('["%s",%s,"%s"]', $k, json_encode($v), $s);
            },
            $data,
            array_keys($data)
        )
    ) . ']';
}
```

Comment: Yeah there is a way, just program it. What have you tried so far? Show us your efforts, because no one will put effort into this if you haven't.

Comment: @klaar I added more info

Comment: We need `$input` and `$_SESSION` sample data as part of your [mcve].